# MySQL/Eloquent force id by left join even if null

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel, eloquent

I have this query wrote in Eloquent :

```
    return TypeModel::with(['apt' => function($q) use ($id){
        $q->leftJoin('build_apt', function($join) use($id){
            $join->on('build_apt.id_apt', '=', 'apt.id_apt');
            $join->on('build_apt.id_build', '=', DB::raw($id->id_build));
        })
    }])
    ->get()
    ->toJson();
```

Equivalent SQL :

```
SELECT * 
FROM `apt` 
LEFT JOIN `build_apt` 
    ON  `build_apt`.`id_apt` = `apt`.`id_apt` 
    AND `build_apt`.`id_build` = 1 
WHERE `apt`.`id_typeapt` in (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
```

I have the result I need except one thing, the id given is null :

```
[
    {"id_typeapt":1,"apt":[
        {"id_apt":null,"image_apt":"apt_1.png"}, 
        {"id_aptitude":null,"image_apt":"apt_2.png"}
    ]
]
```

How can I force it to look for the id from the table "apt" and not giving me "null" as a result?

Thanks you!

EDIT : Where clause is coming from the with

```
public function apt(){
    return $this->hasMany(AptModel::class, 'id_typeapt', 'id_typeapt');
}
```

EDIT2 :

`id_apt` was crushed by the other `id_apt` with a simple rename I could retrieve the id :

```
    return TypeModel::with(['apt' => function($q) use ($id){
        $q->leftJoin('build_apt', function($join) use($id){
            $join->on('build_apt.id_apt', '=', 'apt.id_apt');
            $join->on('build_apt.id_build', '=', DB::raw($id->id_build));
        })
    }])->select(DB::raw("*, apt.id_apt as id_apt);
  }])
```

Comment: Where does the `WHERE` clause comes from ? Please show all of your Eloquent code.

Comment: It comes from the `with`. I updated the post

Comment: From SQL perspective, you need to move the `WHERE` clause to the `ON` conditions of the `LEFT JOIN` on  `build_apt`.

Comment: select * from `apt` 
left join `build_apt` 
on `build_apt`.`id_apt` = `apt`.`id_apt` and `build_apt`.`id_build` = 1 
and `apt`.`id_typeapt` in (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)

Answer (score 1):

You are using `LEFT JOIN`, which is what you want, however you have conditions on the joined table in the `WHERE` clause. This actually turns your `LEFT JOIN` to an `INNER JOIN`, since unmatched records will be filtered out by the `WHERE` clause.

You would need to tweak your Eloquent code in order to generate the following SQL query :

```
SELECT * 
FROM `apt` 
LEFT JOIN `build_apt` 
    ON  `build_apt`.`id_apt` = `apt`.`id_apt` 
    AND `build_apt`.`id_build` = 1 
    AND `apt`.`id_typeapt` in (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
```

Comment: In MySQL with this query the column `id_apt` remains `null` because there are no matches in 'build_apt'. The other column was crushing the actual `id_apt` needed. With a rename this is fine now.